# Are "tr A-Z C-ZA-B" and "tr ..A-Z A-ZA-Z" equal?

Tags: tr

If I compare the following two commands:

```
$ echo "HELLO" | tr A-Z C-ZA-B
$ echo "HELLO" | tr ..A-Z A-ZA-Z
```

They both return `JGNNQ`.

Why does `tr` behave this way and do I get the same results. What is the meaning of <dot >?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What did you expect as a difference?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what periods in front of alphabet does. Is this just with tr or is it with alphabet in general?

Why does `..` shift the characters in this case?

Comment: a dot is a dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially what `tr` does is replace the characters of `SET1` with those of `SET2`. Imagine `SET1="abcdef"` and `SET2="123654"`, then the following translations are made:

```
a->1    b->2   c->3
d->6    e->5   f->4
```

In your first example, you translate the 26 characters `A-Z` into `C-ZAB`, this means:

```
SET1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
SET2=CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
```

As you notice there is an offset of 2

The same holds for the second case

```
SET1=..ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
SET2=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
```

The second set is truncated to match the first set, so in the end you have exactly the same translation for the letters, however, you will see a difference with the <dot>.

```
$ echo "HELLO. IS ANYBODY OUT THERE." | tr A-Z C-ZA-B
JGNNQ. KU CPADQFA QWV VJGTG.
$ echo "HELLO. IS ANYBODY OUT THERE." | tr ..A-Z A-ZA-Z
JGNNQB KU CPADQFA QWV VJGTGB
```

Notice the subtle difference, in the second case you also translate the <dot> into the letter `B`.

Comment: I think your last example should be `echo "HELLO. IS ANYBODY OUT THERE." | tr ..A-Z A-ZA-Z`, or?

Comment: @Ralf yes, typo. Thanks for spotting it.